# TextBox String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I just need a little helping regarding the code below. I'm getting String was not recgonized as a valid DateTime from this line. I tried using DateTime.TryParse but it just gives me error and Convert.ToDateTime gives me same error.

> ```
>    if(DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)>=d1 && DateTime.Parse( TextBox4.Text)<=d2)
>     {
> ```

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = KEVS; Initial Catalog = booking; Integrated Security = True; ");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from booking1 where busno='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con);

   // cmd.CommandText = "Select * from booking1 where date='" + TextBox3.Text + "' and busno='" + DropDownList1.Text + "'";
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
         d1 = dr.GetDateTime(2);
         d2 = dr.GetDateTime(3);
    }

   if(DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)>=d1 && DateTime.Parse( TextBox4.Text)<=d2)
    {
         Label14.Text = "bus is already booked by someone";
    }
```

Comment: What is the format of the dates in `TextBox3.Text` and `TextBox4.Text`?

Comment: What is the value of `TextBox3.Text` and `TextBox4.Text`? You'll likely get a lot of comments about SQL Injection as well.

Comment: @MetroSmurf .. and releasing disposable resources, and `select *`..

Comment: @MetroSmurf thank you I got it now! I mixed the formats of days and month. sorry for my bad.

Comment: @Tim Hi tim thanks for the response. I mixed up the dates and months.

Comment: @Josh Can you please tell _exact_ values of `TextBox3.Text` and `TextBox4.Text` with debugging your code?

Answer (score 0):

To address the immediate question, use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) since you're dealing with user input. Only use Parse if you know the value is an actual DateTime representation.

```
DateTime dt3;
DateTime dt4;

if(DateTime.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, out dt3) && dt3 >=d1 && DateTime.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, out dt4) && dt4 <=d2)
```

Then use the values of `dt3` and `dt4` as needed.